# how to Delete duplicate items on asp:dropdownlist, Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have used asp:drowdownlist on dataviewwebpart and is bind with source spdatasource1.
It have multiple duplicate items. How could I delete those duplicate item

`asp:DropDownList runat="server"  id="DropDownList1"  DataValueField="ID"    DataTextField="ProgramMaster" DataSourceID="spdatasource1" AutoPostBack="False" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ToolTip="Select a Program from the list"/>`

Also, It is showing items in following formation ID;#ProgramName. How can I get programName only.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use JQuery to remove duplicates item from asp:dropdownlist and here's the code if in-case somebody might need it. The code works in four part, Get the value from Dropdown, strip off the Duplicates and get the value in usable form, Remove the existing value from Dropdown and last set or append the values back to the dropdown list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var handles= [];               
$('#DropDownList1 option').each(function() { 
var Prog1 = $(this).attr('text');
if(Prog1 != 'All'){
var Prog2 = Prog1.split(';#');
handles.push('All');
handles.push(Prog2[1]);
 }
//Remove The existed Dropdownlist value
$("select#DropDownList1 option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
//$(this).val().remove();
});
//Removing the Duplicates
var individual = [];
for (var i = 0; i<handles.length; i++) {
if((jQuery.inArray(handles[i], individual )) == -1)
{
individual .push(handles[i]);
} 
 }
//Inserting or setting the value from array individual to the dropdownlist.  
var sel =   document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
for(var i = 0; i < individual.length; i++) {
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.innerHTML = individual[i];
opt.value = individual[i];
sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
 });
</script>
```

P.S if the given ID didn't work fine for dropdown, get the ID from IE debugging tool which will be in form ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_a0a2fb36_2203_4d2e_bcd4_6f42243b880f_DropDownList1

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery

```
var usedNames = {};
$("select[name='company'] > option").each(function () {
if(usedNames[this.text]) {
    $(this).remove();
} else {
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
}
});
```

or with server side code try this

```
void RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList ddl)
{

for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
{

ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
string str = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
for (int counter = i + 1; counter < ddl.Items.Count; counter++)
{
ddl.SelectedIndex = counter;
string compareStr = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (str == compareStr)
 {
  ddl.Items.RemoveAt(counter);
  counter = counter - 1;
 }  


}    }     }
```